# Group data split in columns by month in a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a data set that looks like the following (those are expenses for various marketing levers) :

[image]

and I would like a pivot table with this structure :

[image]

However, I do not know how to add the values for the different months, since all values are in different columns, and therefore in different fields in my pivot table. All I can obtain is something like this :

[image]

which is not good because it only shows the individual valuse for each month and there is no way to quickly select the months I want to take into account. Is there a way to do this (without modifying the structure of my data set too much) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting the End user to be able to select any number of Months? Or is it going to be set time frames? By time frames i mean like broke of into Quarters, yearly or maybe even broke into 2 or 4 month periods? If the info is going to be in set time frames we can add columns for those time frames and make it work that way if you want them to be able to select any set up months like (Jan, Mar, Aug) Then as far as I know the only way would require a big change to the structure of the data and you would make Months a column which would mean you would have a row for each Country ItemName Month

Comment: You might be able to do what you are wanting using Calculated fields as well. Which would not require a change to the data structure